# Unity5 admob interstitial not implementing in device

Tags: c#, admob, unity-game-engine

I attached this script to main button onclick and run in unity but it shows `DUMMY SHOW INTERSTITIAL`. When I deploy on my device it gives the message, "unfortunately APP has stopped".
I tried many times by minor changes and some major changes but each time it shows `DUMMY INTERSTITIAL SHOW`, but when is run my app on the device it gives the error of `SORRY, UNFORTUNATELY APP HAS STOPPED`,  this is my main code. Can anyone review this and tell me if any error or what should I do to run this code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using System;

public class AdMobController : MonoBehaviour {

    InterstitialAd interstitial;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {     
        //RequestBanner ();
        RequestInterstitial ();
    }

    public void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "AD_UNIT_ID";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the interstitial with the request.
        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is clicked.
    }

    public void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        print("OnAdLoaded event received.");
        // Handle the ad loaded event.
    }
    public void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        print("Interstitial Failed to load: " + args.Message);
        // Handle the ad failed to load event.
    }
    public void ChangeScene (int sceneToChangeTo) {
        Application.LoadLevel (sceneToChangeTo);

            interstitial.Show ();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are missing the dependencies  required to use Admob.

Go to *Assets* **-->** *Play Services Resolver* **-->** *Android Resolver* **-->** *Resolve Client Jars*.

This will import all the required dependencies into your project.

Comment: I did it but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

First of all just call the

> interstitial.Show

method when you already checked if the interstitial is ready to show. There are methods in the admob api which you can use.
Can you also please explain how you run the code on button click when you call a method in the start method ?

Comment: I just added this script to my button and call this method sceneChange from on click from button inspector,

Comment: Okay the Problem here is that u call the method directly on the Start method so it dosent make a differnce if you click it or not it will call as soon as the class is initialized. Also you should maybe change it so the "interstitial.Show ();" is called before you switch your scene